# Como Busco un registro en una tabla

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

necesito una instruccion para buscar un registro en una tabla con condicion en este codigo cuento los registros que cumplan con la condicion intx = `DCount("*", "[p1]", "[nro_identificacion]= '" & nro & "'")`pero quisiera sustituirla por la de busqueda y me indique si la encontro o no  agradeceria ayuda. Este es la instruccion que quiero sustituir:

DCount("*", "[p1]", "[nro_identificacion]= '" & nro & "'")

Con mas detalle, (vba-access) Con la instruccion Dcount solo cuenta la cantidad de registros que tiene la tabla (p1) con esa condicion (nro_identificacion]= '" & nro &), pero lo que requiero es que lo BUSQUE para extraer los campos necesarios para agregar a otra tabla. Gracias por tu atencion.

Comment: Podes aclarar mejor el problema?

Comment: Con la instruccion Dcount  solo cuenta la cantidad de registros que tiene la tabla (p1) con esa condicion (nro_identificacion]= '" & nro &), pero lo que requiero es que lo BUSQUE para extraer los campos necesarios para agregar a otra tabla. Gracias por tu atencion.

Comment: No lo cuentes en un comentario. Explicalo en la pregunta. Usa el boton [edit] y explica bien que queres hacer. pone un ejemplo. Ademas cuando hablas de tabla, que es? sobre access? sobre excel?

Comment: Entiendo que esto lo solucionaste con el DLOOKUP de la otra pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Con la funcion "DLookUp" que ya viene integrada en el codigo de Visual Basic del Acceess, se utiliza de la siguiente manera:

```
Dim Str As String

Str = Nz(DlookUp("LoQueBusco", "TablaDondeLoBusco", "CondicionQueDebeCumplir"), "")

If Nz(Str, "") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Este es un error, ya que no se encontro lo que se buscaba.", & _ 
           vbExclamation + vbOkOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub/Function
End If
```

De manera mas clara, la funcion DlookUp equivale a realizar una clausula SELECT, como te mencione en el ejemplo, se compone de:

```
SELECT LoQueBusco
FROM   TablaDondeLoBusco
WHERE  CondicionQueSeDebeDeCumplir
```

Se utiliza la funcion NZ(), esto para el control de los errores, es decir, que si viene vacia la busqueda de la funcion DlookUp, no te salga un mensaje de error del entorno, esto solo confundiria al usuario, y pues, finalmente solo se valida si la fucnion "Str" de tipo String viene vacia, ahi es donde estas controlando tu el error, y le puedes poner na mensaje al usuario que se le ha olvidado llenar cierto campo.

Saludos.